# how to change label Title css into Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

my css are

```
label[title="Hot"]{
  display:none;
}
label[title="Cold"]{
  display:none;
}
```

could you help me how can i change this into JavaScript

Comment: Do you mean you need a selector which selects the same elements as the given CSS affects on?

Comment: @Teemu yes u r right

Comment: `dcoument.querySelectorAll('label[title="Cold"], label[title="Hot"]');` selects all those elements.

Comment: @Teemu how to hide display none

Comment: @Md Gosoddin - extending it to @Teemu's answer `dcoument.querySelectorAll('label[title="Cold"], label[title="Hot"]').style.display = "none"`

Comment: @kritiz The NodeList doesn't have `style` property, you've to iterate thorugh the list and set the style of the elements.

Comment: @MdGosoddin Can you show an example of what you're trying to accomplish? Setting inline styles for visibility feels so wrong.

Comment: @Teemu true, my bad, we should iterate through, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to do the same thing in JavaScript. If so, you would need to create a DOM element of type 'label' and set it's properties the same way you would if you were to use `.getElementById` or `.querySelector`. Should look something like:

```
var hot_label = document.createElement('label');
hot_label.title="Hot";
hot_label.display="none";

var cold_label = document.createElement('label');
cold_label.title="Hot";
cold_label.display="none";
```

Then you'd need to put them somewhere. Let's say for example your html has `<div id="tempLabels"></div>`. You would first get the container, then append the new DOM elements.

```
var container = document.getElementById('tempLabels');
container.appendChild(hot_label);
container.appendChild(cold_label);
```

Alternatively you could have one label and change the title:

```
var temp_label = document.createElement('label');

// when temp is hot
temp_label.title="Hot";
temp_label.display="inline-block"; //or whatever display type you're using

// when temp is cold
temp_label.title="Cold";
temp_label.display="inline-block"; //or whatever display type you're using

// hide label
temp_label.display="none";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hot_label = dcoument.querySelector('label[title="hot"]');
var cold_label = dcoument.querySelector('label[title="Cold"]');
//If you want to hide.
hot_label.style.display = "none";
cold_label.style.display = "none";
```